# parsing xml in R - return data frame object

Tags: xml, r

I have success getting example 1 xml as a dataframe object in R but having trouble with example 2.  Does anyone have suggestions on R code to covert data from mtcars.xml into a dataframe?

example 1)

```
library(XML)
# Save the URL of the xml file in a variable

xml.url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"

# Use the xmlTreePares-function to parse xml file directly from the web

xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xml.url)

# Use the xmlRoot-function to access the top node
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
# have a look at the XML-code of the first subnodes:
print(xmltop)[1:2]


# To extract the XML-values from the document, use xmlSApply:

plantcat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

example2)

```
    library(XML)
# Save the URL of the xml file in a variable

doc <- xmlTreeParse(system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML"))


xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(doc)

# Use the xmlRoot-function to access the top node
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
# have a look at the XML-code of the first subnodes:
print(xmltop)[1:2]


# To extract the XML-values from the document, use xmlSApply:

mtcarscat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

Comment: For the first one, `xmlToDataFrame('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml')` does it all in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `xpathSApply`:

```
library(XML)

path <- system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML")
doc <- xmlTreeParse(path, useInternal = TRUE)
root <- xmlRoot(doc)

read.table(text = xpathSApply(root, "//record", xmlValue), 
           col.names = xpathSApply(root, "//variable", xmlValue))
```

giving:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `xml2`:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

catalog_url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
doc <- read_xml(catalog_url)

# get all the "records"
plants <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//PLANT")

# get all the field names
kids <- xml_name(xml_children(plants[1]))

# make a data frame
# - iterate over each record
# - in each record grab each field
# - turn each row into a data frame
# - bind all the data frames together

map_df(plants, function(plant) {
  rbind_list(as.list(setNames(map_chr(kids, function(kid) {
    xml_text(xml_find_one(plant, sprintf(".//%s", kid)))
  }), kids)))
})

## Source: local data frame [36 x 6]
## 
##                 COMMON              BOTANICAL  ZONE        LIGHT PRICE AVAILABILITY
##                  (chr)                  (chr) (chr)        (chr) (chr)        (chr)
## 1            Bloodroot Sanguinaria canadensis     4 Mostly Shady $2.44       031599
## 2            Columbine   Aquilegia canadensis     3 Mostly Shady $9.37       030699
## 3       Marsh Marigold       Caltha palustris     4 Mostly Sunny $6.81       051799
## 4              Cowslip       Caltha palustris     4 Mostly Shady $9.90       030699
## 5  Dutchman's-Breeches    Dicentra cucullaria     3 Mostly Shady $6.44       012099
## 6         Ginger, Wild       Asarum canadense     3 Mostly Shady $9.03       041899
## 7             Hepatica     Hepatica americana     4 Mostly Shady $4.45       012699
## 8            Liverleaf     Hepatica americana     4 Mostly Shady $3.99       010299
## 9   Jack-In-The-Pulpit    Arisaema triphyllum     4 Mostly Shady $3.23       020199
## 10            Mayapple   Podophyllum peltatum     3 Mostly Shady $2.98       060599
## ..                 ...                    ...   ...          ...   ...          ...
```

It could be made a bit more robust by looking for all the possible children names (some "records" might have more or fewer children) but it's sufficient for this example. Doing it this way (getting the value for each element by name) ensures they come back in the right order (order of the elements is not a guarantee).